# How to structure a Docker application that has multiple supervisord entry points?

Tags: docker, supervisord

I'm writing a Python web application that consists of several services - one for the web app itself, one for a queue worker, and one for a dashboard on top of the queue worker. These services are all contained in the same application but need to run independently.

I would like to run all of the services using supervisord in separate Docker containers. Ideally I would have 1 Dockerfile for the entire application and multiple entry points to start the various services independently.

Here's the pattern I have been working with so far:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

# copy app, install dependencies...

COPY supervisor/base.conf /etc/supervisor/base.conf
COPY supervisor/service_1.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/service_1.conf
COPY supervisor/service_2.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/service_2.conf
COPY supervisor/service_3.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/service_3.conf

COPY docker/start_service_1.sh /start_service_1.sh
COPY docker/start_service_2.sh /start_service_2.sh
COPY docker/start_service_3.sh /start_service_3.sh
```

start_service_1.sh:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/conf.d/service_1.conf
```

service_1.conf

```
[include]
files=/etc/supervisor/base.conf # Shared supervisor config for all services

[program:service_1]
command=run service_1
autostart=true
```

This is working just fine for me right now. I can build a single Docker image and start the services in separate containers using their `start_service.sh` scripts.

However, I am wondering if there's a better pattern for something like this. It feels "hacky", but I haven't been able to find any good examples that are similar to my architecture. My issues/concerns are:

1. Duplicate code in the `start_service.sh` scripts.
2. Dockerfile does not have a default entry point or command.
3. If one service gets very large, it will bloat the containers of the other services.

Comment: Do you really need supervisord?  If not, you can `docker run myimage ./start_service_1.sh` and overwrite the CMD at launch time.

Comment: @DavidMaze The frameworks that my services are running recommend using some sort of process manager like supervisor. My app is small enough where it probably doesn't matter that much. However, I'd still have to have those `start_service.sh` scripts, which might be totally fine, I just wanted to see if there was something better out there.